# Does anyone know how I can setup Rasa on any OS?

Tags: rasa, sap-conversational-ai

I've tried my best to follow the instructions for RASA - https://kdta.io/hlWcv setup on different OSs and Docker but everything breaks at one point or another. Does anyone have instructions on how to actually install and then run this tool? I tried the setup instructions of Mac and Linux and docker but each failed.

Comment: Where did they fail? Error message?